# How to do a generic tuple map using a GADT?

Tags: haskell

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

module Main where

import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)

infixl 1 |>
(|>) = flip ($)

data CudaVarAr2d x where VarAr2d :: CudaVarScalar Int -> CudaVarScalar Int -> ByteString -> CudaVarAr2d x
data CudaVarAr1d x where VarAr1d :: CudaVarScalar Int -> ByteString -> CudaVarAr1d x
data CudaVarScalar x where VarScalar :: ByteString -> CudaVarScalar x

data CudaVariable x where
  VarAr2d' :: CudaVarAr2d x -> CudaVariable x
  VarAr1d' :: CudaVarAr1d x -> CudaVariable x
  VarScalar' :: CudaVarScalar x -> CudaVariable x
  VarTuple2 :: CudaVariable x -> CudaVariable y -> CudaVariable (x,y)
  VarTuple3 :: CudaVariable x -> CudaVariable y -> CudaVariable z -> CudaVariable (x,y,z)

size = VarScalar "size"
x1 = VarAr1d' $ VarAr1d size "x1"
x2 = VarAr1d' $ VarAr1d size "x2"
inp = VarTuple2 x1 x2

o1 = VarAr1d' $ VarAr1d size "o1"
o2 = VarAr1d' $ VarAr1d size "o2"
outp = VarTuple2 o1 o2

-- Later I intend to cover all the cases.
varar1d_into_prim_adj :: CudaVariable x -> CudaVariable (x,x)
varar1d_into_prim_adj (VarAr1d' (VarAr1d size name)) = VarTuple2 x1 x2 where
  f suffix = VarAr1d' (VarAr1d size ([name,suffix] |> B.concat))
  x1 = f "_primal"
  x2 = f "_adjoint"

--map_into_prim_adj :: CudaVariable x -> CudaVariable x
map_into_prim_adj x =
  let f = varar1d_into_prim_adj in
  case x of
    VarTuple2 a b -> VarTuple2 (f a) (f b)
    VarTuple3 a b c -> VarTuple3 (f a) (f b) (f c)

main :: IO ()
main = print "Hello"
```

This thing with the tuples killed me in F#-land when I was making an interface for the Cuda compiler, so I am looking for more fertile ground in Haskell-land. I have no idea how to express the type for `map_into_prim_adj` and I was hoping the compiler would do it for me, but that was not the case.

The ultimate goal of this would be to write something like

```
cuda_map_fb 
    (\(x,y) -> x * y)) 
    (\((x_primal,x_adjoint),(y_primal,y_adjoint)) error -> do
        set x_adjoint (x_adjoint + error * y_primal)
        set y_adjoint (y_adjoint + error * x_primal))
```

And have it be typechecked and sent to the compiler, but first I need to figure out how to map a tuple into a primal and an adjoint first. What I am trying to do is a tiny embedded Cuda compiler for a automatic differentiation/deep learning library.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the `accelerate` library and its CUDA backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're doing exactly but here is how you could type `map_into_prim_adj` using the [`TypeFamilies`](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/users-guide/glasgow_exts.html#synonym-families) language extension:

```
type family ResType t :: * where
  ResType (x, y) = ((x, x), (y, y))
  ResType (x, y, z) = ((x, x), (y, y), (z, z))
  -- ...

map_into_prim_adj :: CudaVariable x -> CudaVariable (ResType x)
map_into_prim_adj x =
  let f = varar1d_into_prim_adj in
  case x of
    VarTuple2 a b -> VarTuple2 (f a) (f b)
    VarTuple3 a b c -> VarTuple3 (f a) (f b) (f c)
    -- ...
```

*A little explanation*. A type family is sort of like a function from types to types. In `map_into_prim_adj` if `x` is a `VarTuple2` the type of `x` would be `CudaVariable (a, b)` and the argument to `ResType` would therefore be `(a, b)` which will match the first equation of `ResType` giving us an output type of `((a, a), (b, b))`.

Comment: This seems promising, but I am not sure I understand what type families are supposed to be about, or whether I want a solution such as this. Instead of a GADT encoding I've been considering a finally tagless one as well which would allow me to use typeclass instances to map the tuples. I want to comment more, but I'll save it for later as I obviously need to read some type family tutorials. Right now I am in the middle of it.

Comment: Typefamilies are like functions from one type to another. `map_into_prim_adj` will have different types depending on what the input was so I used a type family to calculate the correct result type.

Comment: So it receives `(x, y)` it will turn it into `((x, x), (y, y))`? The tutorials seem fairly difficult, and I am having difficulty wrapping my head around this on such a short notice. ...Actually looking at the above in `CudaVariable (ResType x)`, is `ResType` the function and `x` the input?